# How to get the check value in jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How to get the value to know if the checkbox is selected?

I'm trying the following code:
(HTML)

```
  <div class="col-md-9" style=" padding-left: 46px; padding-top: 6px;">
       <label class="checkbox checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" id="sequenciaRelatorio">
          <i class="input-helper"></i>
          Ordenar por Seq. de Categoria
          </label>
  </div>
```

Within my js function I put:

```
 var ordenacaoRelatorio = $("input[type='checkbox']").val();

 var routeValues = "pdfExcel=0" + '?rbCampanha=' + rbCampanha + '?rbTabelaPreco=' + rbTabelaPreco +
    '?rbAtivos=' + rbAtivos + '?rbInativos=' + rbInativos + '?rdRetratoPaisagem=' + rdRetratoPaisagem + '?rdOrdenacaoRel=' + rdOrdenacaoRel +
    '?rdAgrupamentoRel=' + rdAgrupamentoRel + '?idsTabelaPreco=' + _idsTabelaPreco + '?posicoesTabelasPreco=' + _posicoesTabelasPreco +
    '?rdImagemRel=' + rdImagemRel + '?rdProdutosSaldoEstoqueFiltro=' + rdProdutosSaldoEstoqueFiltro + '?rdProdutosComSaldoEstoque=' + rdProdutosComSaldoEstoque + '?bCompacto=' + bCompacto + '?sequenciaRelatorio=' + ordenacaoRelatorio;
$.ajax({
    url: '/Sistema/Base/EncodeRoute',
    data: {
        actionName: "RelatorioTabelasPrecoCatalogo",
       ordenacaoRelatorio: ordenacaoRelatorio
    },
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.bServidorFuncionandoRotativa == true) {
            if (result.url !== "") {
                window.open(result.url);

            }

        }

    },
```

Answer (score 0):

put this code in your js, .change() function will execute when you checked the checkbox.

```
 $("#sequenciaRelatorio").change(function() { // this code will execute whenever user change the checkbox
        if(this.checked) { // if its response is 1 markes as checked
            alert('checked');
            $("#sequenciaRelatorio").val('1');
        }else{
            $("#sequenciaRelatorio").val('0');
        }
    });
```